# Filling bars with a color gradient in barplot ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to fill bars with collors accotrding to a color scale.
The problem is that I can achieve that ggplot2 fill all bars with desired tones.
 I am doing:

```
p <- ggplot(data=base_c2, aes(x=c2_inicio, y=incid_usuar)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.8, fill=base_c2$incid_usuar) +
 scale_color_gradient2(midpoint=mean(base_c2$incid_usuar), 
                        low ="#91CF60",mid = "#FFFFBF", high = "#FC8D59",
                         space ="Lab")
p
```

but the result is:[image]

how can achieve a smoooth grtadient?
 (green in low values, yellow in values close to the mean, red for high values)

Comment: Try `scale_fill_gradient2`, bars take color values from `fill`, not `color`.

Comment: It's the same :(

Comment: Also change your ggplot call to `ggplot(data=base_c2, aes(x=c2_inicio, y=incid_usuar, fill = incid_usuar))` and remove `fill=base_c2$incid_usuar` from `geom_bar()`.

Comment: thank you!! it totally worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way:

```
p <- 
  ggplot(data=base_c2, aes(x=c2_inicio, y=incid_usuar, 
                            fill=base_c2$incid_usuar)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.8) +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_gradient2(midpoint=mean(base_c2$incid_usuar), 
                       low ="#91CF60",mid = "#FFFFBF", high = "#FC8D59",
                       space ="Lab") + 
  labs(title = "Numero de incidentes atendidos por usuario según C2")
p
```

[image]